# Buying and Selling in Urban Rivals

Tags: urban-rivals

I have `598 Clintz` and I bought a character for `449 Clintz`. I expected that the Clintz I have will drop to `598-449=149`. But it did not happen. I still have `598 Clintz`. So, how does this work? Also, what would happen if I sell some character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have worked fine,i mean you should have 149cl left and new character,it also goes for selling your characters,you get money and lose character.

You really got the card? it can happen that someone else clicked buy before you and you ended up with blank link and no new character...

Other thing is that you might spend credits instead clintz but it is less probable since credits are used only for buying booster packs as far as i remember.

Comment: Thanks. It happened. I just cleared all cookies and tried again. I have the updated clintz value now.